# Connecting to SQL Server 2014 from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, jdbc, sql-server-2014

I have a problem connecting to SQL-server database through from my android project. I have added **sqljdbc41.jar** file to my /app/libs directory and I have added it to dependencies in my android studio project.

I use following code:

```
package com.konrad.rezerwacje1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class Database_Console {

public static void openConnection(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"‌​);
        String url = "jbdc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=my_db";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    openConnection();
}
}
```

yet i still get this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jbdc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=my_db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

Comment: You have a typo in your url, it should be jdbc (j>d<bc), not j>b<dc. That said, you really should not use a database directly from android, put a webservice in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"‌​);
String url = "jbdc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=my_db";
```

You have to use this :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=my_db";

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
```

Note the different classname, and the fact that prefix `jbdc` in the URL has been changed to `jdbc`.

Comment: that's not the case, i still get the same error message

Comment: @KonradK use this `Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");` instead of this `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`

Comment: `Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
Information:22.04.2017 18:18 - Compilation completed with 4 errors and 0 warnings in 2s 683ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
C:\Users\Konrad\AndroidStudioProjects\Rezerwacje1\app\src\main\java\com\konrad\rezerwacje1\Database_Console.java
Error:(17, 72) Gradle: error: illegal character: '\u200c'
Error:(17, 73) Gradle: error: illegal character: '\u200b'
Error:(17, 74) Gradle: error: ';' expected`

Comment: ok now this is another problem @KonradK in another part of code you have to share more code, or ask another question

Comment: @KonradK but this is not what i already suggest you have to use `String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=my_db";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");`

Comment: This is incorrect, the URL prefix `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver:` was used for the SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver, they changed it to `jdbc:sqlserver:` in 2005.

Comment: how did you explain this error @MarkRotteveel `Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] Information:22.04.2017 18:18 - Compilation completed with 4 errors and 0 warnings in 2s 683ms Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. C:\Users\Konrad\AndroidStudioProjects\Rezerwacje1\app\src\ma‌​in\java\com\konrad\r‌​ezerwacje1\Database_‌​Console.java Error:(17, 72) Gradle: error: illegal character: '\u200c' Error:(17, 73) Gradle: error: illegal character: '\u200b' Error:(17, 74) Gradle: err`

Comment: Sounds like a copy paste error, `\u200b` is character ZERO WIDTH SPACE, probably introduced by copying things from the comments.

Comment: mark also the Class.forName i think it should be `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` and not `Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"‌​);`

Comment: Although it is suspicious that `Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver")` doesn't throw an exception, as that is the drivername of the SQL Server 2000 driver, current versions indeed use `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Comment: so the problem is in driver thank you for the information @MarkRotteveel appreciate it

Comment: after applying the changes you guys mentioned i still get the `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jbdc:microsoft:sqlserver://127.0.0.1` exception, maybe it's a problem with how I add the .jar file to my app. Can you explain exactly how to do it? (same thing happened when i used jtds driver as someone proposed below)

Comment: no you don't change the **jbdc** it should **jdbc** --->**d before the b** not the inverse @KonradK

Comment: I'm sorry, you are of course right. 
Still, after fixing the typo I get the no suitable driver exception

Comment: yes @KonradK your URL is incorrect it should be `jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=my_db` thanks to mark he correct my answer

Comment: Oh, thanks, I have finally moved passed the driver part, now i have some issues with login int DB but i'll try to solve it myself

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a requirement to go with `sqljdbc41.jar`, then you might consider using the `jtds` driver for your requirement to connect to SQL Server 2014 with Android Studio. There are tons of articles that can help you start with this set of technologies.

For a primer, here are the details:

- Download the JTDS driver from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/)
- Then import this jar into your Android Studio, eg: `jtds-1.2.5.jar`
- Use the following details in your code:

  ```
  Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/DATABASE;user=sa;password=p@ssw0rd");
  ```